# How to sort regions in my code

Tags: c#, region

I got more than **13000** lines of codes which are divided in more than **30** regions in my `C#` application.

Is there a way to sort the regions by their names so that I could easily find the codes I want?

**Update**

In my defense: It's my `winform` class which contains many controls and many user controls, which each one does something big which are depended to other controls. and there are many other codes in other classes which I managed to make some classes for them.

Comment: 13000 lines in 30 regions in one class? One file?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yes. It's a really big project

Comment: @AlexJolig It is not a "really big project". It is a "really bad architecture".

Comment: I would strongly recommend trying to refactor and split up the giant class into multiple classes with limited functions. That should help you not only to manage this complexity, but make any changes easier!

Comment: That is a very big smell in code. Start by turning regions into methods, then group methods and fields into classes and finally split the classes across files

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev So is there any way to sort regions in a bad architecture project?

Comment: If your *one* class has 13000 lines :o then you must have a look at better designing approach or at least split it into multiple *cs* files using `partial` class.

Comment: @AlexJolig It is highly dependend on your code, its usage etc. Paste your code somewhere and we will try to do something.

Comment: `Region` was intended to seperate user and auto generated code, use `search` instead of maintain the sorting of those legacy regions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430198/stylecop-sa1124-donotuseregions-is-reasonable

Comment: @AlexJolig: There is a way to do it. First understand all the processes/ activities that 13,000 lines do. Divide them in to meaningful entities. For an example 13,000 lines can be your "school management system". In that you will have student, teacher, class, course, exam, question, answer etc. Each one of them should be a class in your system.

Comment: Sorting regions by their name - will that actually help you anyway? (Better options are already being discussed in the comments)

Comment: This may be relevant _[Why do we need separate “.swift” files for each class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942173/why-do-we-need-separate-swift-files-for-each-class/26942671#26942671)_.  Though it mentions Swift the concept may apply

Comment: Are those `region`s nested? or is there only one level?

Comment: @nozzleman They are at the same level

Comment: Maybe NArrange can do that, otherwise, you could write a little app using a regex to match regions like `/^#region.*#endregion$/s` and sort them your self....